# Using TDataset with XML Fields in Microsoft SQL Server causes weird exception

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delphi, ado

I am currently tracking down a rare problem in our SQL generator and was able to narrow down the source of the problem. I created a sample with three testcases to show you the exact behaviour:

```
QUery.Close;
//Query.SQL.Text := Format('select Options, JobID, StatusMessage from ServerJob where JobID = %d', [ServerJobID]); // #1
//Query.SQL.Text := Format('select JobID, Options, StatusMessage from ServerJob where JobID = %d', [ServerJobID]); // #2
//Query.SQL.Text := Format('select JobID, StatusMessage, Options from ServerJob where JobID = %d', [ServerJobID]); // #3
Query.Open;

try
  JobID := Query.FieldByName('JobID').AsInteger; // #1 raises exception
                                                 // #2 ok
                                                 // #3 ok

  StatusMsg := Query.FieldByName('StatusMessage').AsString; // #1 never reaches this point
                                                            // #2 raises exception
                                                            // #3 ok
except
  on Exp: Exception do
  begin
    ExpMsg := Exp.Message; // #1 Fehler bei einem aus mehreren Schritten bestehenden Vorgang. Prüfen Sie die einzelnen Statuswerte.
                           // #2 Fehler bei einem aus mehreren Schritten bestehenden Vorgang. Prüfen Sie die einzelnen Statuswerte.
                           // #3 never reaches this point

    Query.Connection.Errors.Count; // #1 1
                                   // #2 1
                                   // #3 never reaches this point

    Query.Connection.Errors[0].Description; // #1 Expression illegal in evaluator
                                            // #2 Expression illegal in evaluator
                                            // #3 never reaches this point
    end;
  end;
```

The field "Options" is of type XML. So my observation is, that if I reference a field having xml as datatype, all subsequent fields cannot be referenced anymore using TDataset.FieldByName without raising an exception.

Is this some known bug??

P.S.
This is the schema of the concerning table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServerJob](
    [JobID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Cpu] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [Ram] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [VitalSign] [datetime] NULL,
    [Options] [xml] NULL,
    [StatusMessage] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JobID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle and SQL server 2014.

Comment: Maybe try casting Options as a varchar?

Comment: Your q seems to be lacking the basic information needed for readers to try to reproduce the problem.  Can you show the DDL for your ServerJob table, view, stored proc or whatever it is?

Comment: casting option as varchar by cast(option as varchar(max)) solves this particular problem but I need to understand whats going wrong here in order to gain a deeper understanding helping to fix such problems more efficiently in the future...

Comment: Have you tried googling your exception?  There seem to be quite a few issues in this regard...

Comment: I have, even though I could of course have overseen something. What I have read using google were plenty of questions concerning the meaning of the exception text. This is however not the problem I am describing here, as I know what the exception text is saying (actually that its required to iterate through the error list of the ado connection), what I am actually doing...

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning that the value of options is null. So any errors raising from invalid xml characters can be excluded

Comment: Good Question: its Delphi 10 Seattle, and Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I'll check it out immediately and will report back :-)

Comment: I check both, changing the fieldname and the datatype. The problem definitely only appears if the datatype of the field is of type xml.

Comment: @Johan - this solved the problem - many thanks!!

Comment: I think you can vote to close your own question with the duplicate. And you're welcome.